# Can't use loop 2 times in the same twig file

Tags: php, symfony, loops, twig, silex

Anybody knows why when I'm creating 2 loops in TWIG template from the same array, only the first one is displayed, created second time is skipped?

```
{% for category in categories %}
   {{ category['name'] }} //works ok
{% endfor %}

{% for category in categories %}
   {{ category['name'] }} //second time not working
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess would be that there's something internal in twig that's going wrong. That would make it technically a bug in twig. 

Have you tried using a different variable name in the second loop?

Comment: sorry, i can't reproduce your behaviour. check this fiddle http://twigfiddle.com/0mlt2g

Comment: Are you iterating something like a query result? or something that need to be rewinded?

Comment: Yes, it's query result, but it's added as a Global Variable in $app['twig']. I've read that twig has some bugs, when it comes to for loops, but I didn't excepted I wouldn't go through it...

Comment: @Daniel try to copy the data into another array before pass it to the twig template and see what happen

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working". Is it erroring? Is rendering of anything from the twig not being done after the first loop, but before the second? Is stuff rendered after each loop rendering OK? Is that code *exactly* what you have, or is it basically pseudo code? What have you done by way of your own troubleshooting? Your question is a bit vague to say anything meaningful about it, TBH. Try reading: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and http://sscce.org/ (the latter is less applicable here, granted).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this variable for reassign :

- loop.index       The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
- loop.index0  The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)
- loop.revindex    The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1
  indexed)

  - loop.revindex0    The number of iterations from the end of the
    loop (0 indexed)

Comment: What has this to do with OP's question/problem?